# ForkJoinPool commonPool() in java

Tags: java

How do I check the number of threads created by "ForkJoinPool commonPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();" in java? Is the degree of parallelism the same as number of threads created by the commonpool()? How do we create threads greater than the number of core cpu?

Comment: You actually have three questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to know the number of threads that are currently running within the pool you need to invoke the ***getRunningThread()*** method. This method returns only an **estimation** of the number of threads that are currently running, which implies all the threads that are not waiting in a join call or in variants of this type of invocation.
2. The level of parallelism does not correspond to the number of threads created within a pool. This value is initially used to define the ***core pool size*** which determines how many workers can stay alive at the same time. The ***pool size*** instead corresponds to the number of existing workers that are either running a task or simply in idle. However, even though the parallelism level stays the same throughout the whole forkJoinPool's existence, the ***pool size*** value is adjusted according to its workload. In fact, if the pool continues to receive further requests, then its ***pool size*** is incremented up to a ***Maximum Pool Size*** value. Instead, if the pool does not receive any further requests for a certain period of time called ***Keep Alive Time*** then the workers are terminated until their number reaches the ***core pool size*** once again.
3. By default, the level of parallelism is equal to the number of physical processors to ensure sort of an actual parallelism. However, this value can be set up manually via some of the ForkJoinPool's constructors and it cannot be changed once an instance has been produced. Furthermore, according to the documentation, the level of parallelism cannot exceed the value 32767.

By the way, I highly suggest you to give a look to the documentation of the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) classes. They're really well written and with in-depth clarifications of the many aspects that characterize them.

Answer (score 1):

You can get number of threads by calling static method of forkjoin pool.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#getCommonPoolParallelism--

There are other size methods as well.
if you create your own pool you can also call instance method `getParallelism`.

You can also monitor forkjoinpool by getting steal count. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#getStealCount--